# Animating custom chart SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm trying to create a chart with SwiftUI, and I want to animate each rectangle so that the first one appears 0.5 seconds after the view is displayed, the second one after that, and so on, creating a smooth animation for the chart.

How can I achieve this staggered fade-in animation for the rectangles in SwiftUI?

This is what I've tried, but the code isn't yielding the result I envisioned.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ChartBar: View {
    @State private var visibleRectangles: [Bool] = []

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ZStack(alignment: .bottom) {
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8)
                    .fill(Color.gray.opacity(0.1))
                    .frame(width: 10)
                VStack(spacing: 1) {
                    ForEach(0..<5, id: \.self) { index in
                        Rectangle()
                            .fill(Color.blue) // Use your desired color
                            .frame(width: 10, height: 20)
                            .opacity(visibleRectangles.indices.contains(index) ? (visibleRectangles[index] ? 1 : 0) : 0)
                            .onAppear {
                                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + Double(index) * 0.5) {
                                    visibleRectangles.append(true)
                                }
                            }
                    }
                }
            }

            Text("31/12")
                .font(.system(size: 20))
                .foregroundColor(Color.black.opacity(0.7))
                .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 4).fill(Color.gray.opacity(0.1)))
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ChartBar()
    }
}

@main
struct MyApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First a proper model would be better than relying on an array of `Bool`.

```
struct BarModel: Identifiable, Equatable{
    var id = UUID()
    var visible: Bool = false
}
```

then in your `ChartBar` `ForEach` loop use a `zip` of the `visibleRectangles` indices and the array itself. Inside the loop you can use both values to access and manipulate the `visibleRectangles` array and its values.

In order to make the rectangles appear from bottom to top subtract the index from the `visibleRectangles` array count. And last use the animation modifier to animate the opacity.

```
struct ChartBar: View {
    @State private var visibleRectangles: [BarModel] = (0...9).map{_ in BarModel()}

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ZStack(alignment: .bottom) {
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8)
                    .fill(Color.gray.opacity(0.1))
                    .frame(width: 10)
                VStack(spacing: 1) {
                    ForEach(Array(zip(visibleRectangles.indices,visibleRectangles)), id: \.0) { index, model in
                        Rectangle()
                            .fill(Color.blue) // Use your desired color
                            .frame(width: 10, height: 20)
                            .opacity( model.visible ? 1 : 0)
                            .animation(.spring, value: visibleRectangles)
                            .onAppear {
                                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + Double((visibleRectangles.count - index)) * 0.5) {
                                    var model = model
                                    model.visible = true
                                    visibleRectangles[index] = model
                                }
                            }
                    }
                }
            }

            Text("31/12")
                .font(.system(size: 20))
                .foregroundColor(Color.black.opacity(0.7))
                .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 4).fill(Color.gray.opacity(0.1)))
        }
    }
}
```